# How does one tell if a new month has started? php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have the dates stored in a mySQL table from 2010 - 2040 in the following format:

2012-01-02

I SELECT each date from the table and display them in a while - mysql_fetch_assoc loop

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo $row["date"];

}
```

how can I check that a new month has started?  I suspect I need to place the current month counter in a var using explode()... but how can a comparison be made since the var will be overwritten in the while loop

```
if(old month != new month){
    do something..
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$old_month = '';

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $row["date"]);
  if($old_month != $month) {
    $old_month = $month;
    echo 'new month';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`date_parse`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php) to parse almost any date format into its components. For example:

```
$date = date_parse("2012-01-02");
var_dump($date);
```

Will output:

```
array(12) {
  ["year"]=>
  int(2012)
  ["month"]=>
  int(1)
  ["day"]=>
  int(2)
  ["hour"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["minute"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["second"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["fraction"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["is_localtime"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

...and your code would be something like this:

```
$month = false;
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
    $date = date_parse( $row["date"] );

    if( $month != $date["month"] ) {
        $month = $date["month"];
        echo "month: {$month}<br />";        
    }

}
```

You should really stop using [`mysql_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) functions, they are being deprecated. Give [`mysqli_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) a try, and if you don't know which one is more suitable, [read this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 0):

if you need just month then you don't have to explode the date format in php, you can get the month in mysql query like

```
$query = "select month(date) as mont from table_name";
```

and check the rest stuff..

Answer (score 0):

You could do it within your query, using a storage variable:

```
set @prevmonth := null;

select if(month(datefield) <> month(@prevmonth), true, false) AS new_month, @prevmonth := month(datefield), ....
FROM ...
```

then simply check this new derived `new_month` field in your fetch code - it'll be 1/true anytime you've reached a new month.

Note: because the first row's comparison will be working against a null @prevmonth, the first row comes out as 0/false. You may want that first row to be true, but that's beyond the scope of all this.